# Azure web app service - Angular App making calls to login.microsoft.com CORS Issue

Tags: angular, azure, cors, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal

Im currently experiencing some trouble understanding how I can allow cross origin calls in my angular app when it is hosted on Azure.

the call im making is to
https://login.microsoftonline.com/application_id/oauth2/v2.0/token to get a token to make further api calls to the Microsoft graph.

Currently I use a chrome extension called "Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-origin" and my site works fine when this plugin is active. ofcourse this is far from desireable. And I would prefer if I didnt need this extension

In my locally hosted environment I create a proxy config, added it to the launch options in my angular.json file and it works like that without the extension.

Now the way I deploy my angular app to my app service is first I build it using 'ng build' and then I use the visual studio code extension "azure app service" too easily deploy it to my app service

my understanding is that there isn't a way to add the proxy config to my build and I should be able to configure a proxy or do something similar in my azure app service.

Here are some screenshots.

App registration:
[image]

Error message
[image]

I would like to stress that I am making calls to an external api namely login.microsoftonline.com
So I cant add it the CORS section in my app service. Since this seems to be the solution I find for most people with the same issue

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you get CORS error when making calls to token endpoint or Microsoft Graph? Can you share some screenshots from browser debugger console and also the app registration reply URLs on AD or ADB2C?

Comment: Im getting the CORS error when making calls to the token endpoint. ive added some extra screenshots to my original post.

Comment: OK. Looks like you have bypassed the CORS check from local so it was working but it wont work when hosted on Azure. Which grant type are you using, Implicit or Auth code? Check the msal or adal js which ever library you are using for its configuration for implicit or auth code grant. These are the recommended grant types for SPAs.

Comment: Im not using a library. I use direct http calls using the http client provided by angular. Here is a picture of the request https://imgur.com/a/D48jNUI.

Comment: I see you are using client_credentials grant_type which should not be used in your scenario because its for when a service interacts with AD to authenticate. In your case you have an App which will be used by a person so the grant_type should either be  `implicit` or `auth code` . Also, you should use `msal` or `adal js` libraries which have interfaces built for such purposes rather than you writing your own from scratch.

Comment: I understand that i shouldn't use it. Unfortunately the way the app is supposed to work is without logging in... As far as i understand it this is only possible when i register the premissions needed as application premissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I have found a way to make it work.

In you azure portal go to advanced Tools > Go > Site Extensions > Gallery > Search for reverse proxy and add it.

Then edit your web.config file and add the following rule

```
<rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
       //This is the url your need to call in your http request in angular
      <match url="^login?(.*)" /> 
       //This is the url that actually gets called
      <action type="Rewrite" url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{R:1}" /> 
</rule>
```

This will create a proxy for your angular app much like the proxy config file did in a locally hosted angular app.

Answer (score -1):

I think this blog will useful to you.

[Fixing CORS Issues in Your Front-End Angular 7/8 App with Angular CLI Proxy Configuration](https://www.techiediaries.com/fix-cors-with-angular-cli-proxy-configuration/)

How to Fix CORS Issues?
Now that we have learned why CORS issues may occur when developing your Angular application. how to fix them?

There are two ways:

1. Configure the server to send the appropriate CORS headers
2. Configure Angular CLI proxy

Comment: Unfortunately configuring the client proxy only works for local environment and not when I deploy to azure. and i cant access the backend server since its not mine.

Comment: `backend server` ? Are you referring to Microsoft?

Comment: @JasperDeSmet Or is your api interface service address?

Comment: Yes, Sorry I meant the https://login.microsoftonline.com/application_id/oauth2/v2.0/token endpoint

Comment: https://www.pshul.com/2020/03/29/authenticate-your-angular-9-to-azure-ad-using-msal/

Comment: Please follow the tutorial and try again, normally this will not happen. If you have time tomorrow, I will re-send the answer for your reference according to the screenshot of the tutorial, if you have not solved it.

Comment: Hi Jason, this is an approach when using msal unfortunately I am unable to use msal. Since as far as i know this requires the user to sign which is not desired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224341/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-jasper-de-smet).

Comment: Which document do you refer to and how to implement ad login, please tell me the document, and the angular version you are using, I will post a detailed tutorial for you.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for your efforts in trying to help me. I have found a solution and answered my own question.